# How to dissect or parse 'as regards'?

Tags: grammar

> [**as regards**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as-regards?q=as+regards) = concerning; in respect of
>
> 2. **regard**  [with object] {archaic} = (Of a thing) relate to; `concern`
>
> [ES](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22as%20regards%22%20Author%3A%22Madison%2C%20James%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=5&sr=) [= Example Sentence]: The condition of the University, **as regards** its finances, is explained by the acc[oun]ts. of the Bursar & Proctor, also communicated.

As per the above, because **regard =** `concern`, this question also applies to 'as concerns'.

I wish to delve into the definition, which I already understand and so ask NOT about. Something feels missing in **as regards** ? I am guessing that **as** operates as a conjunction here, and **regard** a (conjugated verb), but is a subject or object missing?

In the ES above, the direct object seems to be 'its finances'. But what's the subject?

Comment: This is not the *concern* definition.  This is "relate to"... As this relates to farro, flaxseeds can....

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual example sentence? I don't see that sentence anywhere on the link you posted... also, if you're just trying to define what farro is, you'd be better served with a wikipedia link... that one is particularly un-useful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farro

Comment: @Catija Thanks for your comment. I actually contrived that example sentence. Should I find another? I'll update my OP with the Wikipedia link later; I learned about all these healthy foods from that Time website.

Comment: You should find an example sentence in a real document... I'm not sure your example itself makes sense, which is what the problem could be... I mean, clearly I can guess at what it means but that's sort of the wonder of English.

Comment: Your example sounds like Jabberwocky; this is not a good example when talking semantics.

Comment: As regards *as regards*, the 18th century didn't like it. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(as+regards)&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28as%20regards%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I suppose that big dummy, It, was on holiday.

Answer (score 1):

*As regards* is a prepositional phrase, similar to *in between* or *in the middle of*.

I've heard the term *with regard(s) to* and *as regards to/with* on occasion.  That and I can see where *regards* almost sounds/looks like a verb.  The *to* on the end is not always needed.

*Regards* in *as regards* is, I believe, technically a plural noun that is part of a prepositional phrase.

> The condition of the University, as regards its finances, is explained by the acc[oun]ts. of the Bursar & Proctor, also communicated.

The subject of this sentence is *The condition of the University* and the verb is *is explained*.

*Condition* is the main, single-word subject - and *condition* is qualified/modified by *of the university*, and the entire phrase *condition of the university* is further qualified/modified by *as regards its finances*.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to break "as regards" into pieces; the syntax is archaic but the fixed expression has remained. It can safely be replaced by *regarding* or *with regard to* and is a synonym for *concerning*.

Comment: Sorry, but how does this answer my question? I declared that `I wish to delve into the definition, which I already understand and so ask NOT about.` So I don't want to replace it.

Comment: The question is "How to dissect or parse 'as regards'?" The answer is, "don't." If you are curious about the etymology of the phrase or its original grammatical function, the question should go to linguistics.stackexchange.com or english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Should your answer be a comment then? It doesn't directly answer my question.